# Create attribute option using Data patch in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, installation, patch-data

I am creating a product attribute with option using Magento 2.3 Data patch.

Used below code.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddFeatureAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{

private $moduleDataSetup;
private $eavSetupFactory;
public $_storeManager;
private $logger;
protected $_dir;
public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;  
    $this->_dir = $dir;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function apply()
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

    $fileName = 'attributes.csv';
    $pubPath = $this->_dir->getPath('pub');
    $attributeFile = $pubPath.'/'.$fileName;
    $arrResult = array();
    if(($handle = fopen($attributeFile, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 1;
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $col_count = count($data);
            $arrResult[] = $data;               
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arrResult as $line) {
        if($i > 0){
            $attributeCode = $line[0];                    
            $attributeName = $line[1];
            $inputType = strtolower($line[2]);
            $options = $line[3];
          $type = 'int';
      $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
           $attributeCode,
           [
             'type' => $type,
             'group' => 'General',
             'backend' => '',
             'frontend' => '',
             'label' => $attributeName,
             'input' => $inputType,
             'class' => '',
             'source' => '',
             'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible' => true,
             'required' => false,
             'user_defined' => true,
             'searchable' => false,
             'filterable' => true,
             "filterable_in_search" => '1',
             'comparable' => false,
             'visible_on_front' => true,
             'used_in_product_listing' => true,
             'unique' => false,                 
             'option' => [
                'values' => $options,
               ],
             'system' => 1                    
             ]
           );
       }
     $i++;
   }

  }

public static function getDependencies()
 {
    return [];
 }

 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
 public function getAliases()
  {
     return [];
  }
}
```

The sample csv file is like below

[image]

The above code not creating the options, please someone help me on that how can we create a attribute with options. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try following way.. 
Here my attribute is **Color**

> Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/AddColorProductAttribute.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * Class AddColorProductAttribute
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data
 */
class AddColorProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'color',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'color',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Color::class,
                'frontend' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'backend' => '',
                'sort_order' => '30',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'default' => null,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,grouped,bundle,configurable,virtual',
                'group' => 'General',
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'option' => ''
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'color');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```

Vendor/Module/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Color.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source;

/**
 * Class Color
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source
 */
class Color extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [
        
        ];
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColumns()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        return [
        $attributeCode => [
        'unsigned' => false,
        'default' => null,
        'extra' => null,
        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length' => 255,
        'nullable' => true,
        'comment' => $attributeCode . ' column',
        ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = [];
        
        $index = 'IDX_' . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = ['type' => 'index', 'fields' => [$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()]];
        
        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $store
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return $this->eavAttrEntity->create()->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can we import from csv and create the options. as like in the question.

Comment: @jafarpinjar you need to logic add in model class file

Comment: Yea I have logic used in my patch file, can you help as in that please

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\CustomProductAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Zend_Validate_Exception;

/**
 * Add custom select attribute
 *
 * Class ProductAttribute
 */
class ProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $_moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $_eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the patch
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->_moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'clothing_materials', [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'sort_order' => 210,
            'label' => 'Clothing Materials',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Moazzam\CustomProductAttribute\Model\Source\Customdropdown',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get Dependencies
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get alisas
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\CustomProductAttribute\Model\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

/**
 * Make the option for custom dropdown source model
 *
 * Class Customdropdown
 * @package Moazzam\CustomProductAttribute\Model\Source
 */
class Customdropdown extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Make the option for source model
     *
     * @return array|array[]|null
     */
    public function getAllOptions(): ?array
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('--Select--'), 'value' => ''],
                ['label' => __('Cotton'), 'value' => 1],
                ['label' => __('Wool'), 'value' => 2],
                ['label' => __('Linen'), 'value' => 3],
                ['label' => __('Viscose'), 'value' => 4]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```